# How does dnf-automatic send emails without knowing a password?

Tags: email-server, centos8, dnf

In the dnf-automatic config file `automatic.conf` I see the following lines under the email section.

```
[email]
# The address to send email messages from.
email_from = sender@example.com

# List of addresses to send messages to.
email_to = receiver@example.com

# Name of the host to connect to to send email messages.
email_host = mail.mailServer.com
```

How does dnf-automatic send an email without knowing the password of the sender `sender@example.com`?

I don't see a spot to put the password.  I must be missing something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, sending email via SMTP doesn't require authentication, and you can just spoof any `From` and `Return-Path` address (unless restricted). The email feature on [DNF Automatic](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/automatic.html) seems to rely on that.

DNF is supposed to be *the next-generation replacement for YUM*, but it doesn't have much options regarding sending mail. Although [complained](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1279773#c4) in 2016, it doesn't support STARTTLS for encrypting the mail, and it doesn't support SMTP authentication.

However, DNF Automatic supports dropping mail to Sendmail using `emit_via = command_email`. See the documentation for the [`[command_email]` section](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/automatic.html#command-email-section). This way you can control the message before it leaves the server.